# How to inject dependencies in directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in my angular application.

Below application is not the actual app but it minimal small app that represent my issue. Any sort of help is appreciated.

I have used resolve while declaring the route like this.

Below is the function that needs to be resolved

```
angular.module('routerApp').formItemModel = function(){
  return {
    test: function(){
      return {name: 'Jenish'}
    }
  };
}
```

and route definition like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('home.list', {
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
    resolve: $injector.instantiate(angular.module("routerApp").formItemModel, {}),
    controller: function($scope, test) {
        $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
        $scope.name = test.name;
        }
    })
```

resolver and app works perfect if I do have html like this: (**partial-home-list.html**)

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="dog in dogs">{{ dog }}</li>
</ul>
name: {{name}}
```

But I am in situation where I need to move this name to the directive so I created test directive like this.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('routerApp').directive('test', function () {
        var linker = function (scope, element) {

        }

        var controllerFunction = function ($scope, test) { //How to inject test here as it reports error **Unknown provider: testProvider <- test**
            $scope.name = test.name;
        }

        return {
            controller: controllerFunction,
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            link: linker
        };
    });

}())
```

Updated **partial-home-list.html** like below

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="dog in dogs">{{ dog }}</li>
</ul>
name: {{name}}
<test></test>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YCcTfnQev4vh9JPNWJTb?p=preview) is plunk for the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inject data resolved in state in directive because directive can be used outside `ui-view` so injection will be invalid. You shall pass data from controller to view like this:

```
scope: {
    data: '='
}
```

View:

```
<test data="test"></test>
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M8uDGLZlvx0mM6hEIS4v?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the transclude options for your issue. Like this

remove the controller from your scope and then add the

```
transclude:true
```

option in the directive.

```
<div>
  <div>
      <b>This is directive content with </b>
  </div>
  <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

and then you can use your directive like this

```
<test>This is the name {{name}}</test>
```

So the name will be taken from the outer scope not from the directive scope.

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OkusBf?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Dinesh, good to see you here. Unfortunately above solution did not work. Run you plunker and click/navigate to List page/route you will see that scope.name does not render anything instead it shows {{name}} which means your dependancies has not been injected properly in to the directive scope.